# Xamarin - ask again for device location

Tags: xamarin, location, xamarin.essentials

I am using Xamarin.Essentials. When I try to get the last known location, the message about device location permission is shown.
If I deny the permission the `PermissionException` is caught.

How I can check for location and fired again the location permission message?

```
try
{
    var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
    if (location != null)
    {
        await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(Nav_to_MAP);
    }
}
catch (PermissionException pEx)
{
    // if deny location
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/481) was opened last year, this is the response from James Montemagno:

> Right now it will request the permission for you based on how the system handles it. On iOS a permission can only be requested once and on Android, it can be multiple times. If the user declines you will get a permission denied exception.
>
> You can use the Permission Plugin today to handle checking and requesting
>   https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin
>
> I will open a new proposal for permissions as they are a tad bit tricky.

So, You could use the [Permissions Plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) to check for the permission before asking. like so:

```cs
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
    }

    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
    //Best practice to always check that the key exists
    if (results.ContainsKey(Permission.Location))
        status = results[Permission.Location];
}

if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    try
    {
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
        if (location != null)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(Nav_to_MAP);
        }
    }
    catch (PermissionException pEx)
    {
        // if deny location
    }
}
```

See the [Docs](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin#in-action) on how to set it up